# Design: A general interface config-reader in C++

Tags: c++, oop, templates, design-patterns

I'm about to design a config-reader which reads data from a file. The data in file may be different types like int/float/string ...

I hope the config-reader has a simple interface, so people can easily use it.

First, I wrote listed all the types

`enum class DataType { INT, UINT32, UINT64, FLOAT, STRING, ARRAY, USER_TYPE, BADTYPE };`

Then, I wrote the "base" class for all types

```
class BasicType{
public:
    DataType value_type;
public:
    BasicType() : value_type(DataType::USER_TYPE){}
    virtual bool parse(const string& ) {}
    virtual string toString(){ return ""; }
};
```

Then, I continue writing each specific type implementations, something like

```
template <int _type>
class BuildInType: public BasicType
{
private:
    // TODO replace this with boost variant or so
    int value_int;
    uint32_t value_uint32;
    uint64_t value_uint64;
    float value_float;
    string value_string;

public:
    BuildInType() { 
        value_type = static_cast<DataType>(_type);
    }
    void bool parse(const string& data_field){ ... }
};

typedef BuildInType < static_cast<int>(DataType::INT)    > IntType;
typedef BuildInType < static_cast<int>(DataType::UINT32) > Uint32Type;
typedef BuildInType < static_cast<int>(DataType::UINT64) > Uint64Type;
...
```

Here Let's just forget Array-type and USER-Defined type

And for the interface,

```
class Parser{
    ...
    BasicType* read_next(){
        //The parse will read the data from file
        //and return something like &IntType, &FloatType or so
};

Parser p("some file");
while(true){
    BasicType* b = p.read_next();
    if(!b)break;
    // Here I'm trying to convert BaseType back to IntType/FloatType etc, 
    // because I want to fetch value_int/value_float ... defined in these derived-classes
}
```

Here after `read_next()`, we get a BasicType pointer which points to its derived class. Here I want to recover the orignal derived class. there any good way to do the "conversion"? or if there're any better ways for this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here I want to recover the orignal derived class.

```
if (const IntType* p = dynamic_cast<const IntType*>(b))
    do something with p->value_int;
else ...
```

> if there're any better ways for this problem?

Hard to say given no background on your robustness/performance/memory-usage etc. requirements, why you're not storing them in the actual type as they're read (i.e. type-safe "deserialisation"), why you're not using an existing library etc..  Anyway, in a similar space you might like to Google for docs on `boost::variant` and/or `boost::lexical_cast` - they can be helpful for similar storage/conversions.